# newline character php python

Tags: php, python, newline

I have a python script (p.py)with a text like this

```
print "Hello"+"\n"
print "World"
```

I am running this file in wamp under php / apache

```
<?php 

$output = system("C:\\python27\\python.exe p.py")

?>
```

I get the following on my browser

```
Hello World
```

without new line

How do I make sure the new line character appears.
I also tried `"\r\n"`

Comment: What do you need the '\n' for?  Can you just use <br/> instead?

Comment: If you are using php to create an HTML page with a python script then you need to produce some HTML.  The <br/> tag is an HTML tag which breaks lines.  You could simply replace your '\n' with '<br/>' and it would break the line between 'Hello' and 'World'.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will need to wrap this in `<pre>` tags, or use `<br/>`.

Try viewing something like:

```
<p>
This is
a test
</p>
```

In a web browser. You will get no newline. That's because HTML pretty much ignores newlines. You will have to use the `<br/>` tag for this.

Answer (score 2):

Evidently the output is HTML. If you inspect the source text of the page, you probably will see the newline.

Either use `<br>` or:

```
<?php 
header("Content-Type: text/plain");
$output = system("C:\\python27\\python.exe p.py")
?>
```